# Vertical alignment problem

Tags: vertical-alignment

I'm trying to draw a callout that has a nice big `i` on the left side, and then a bunch of text filling most of the body. The following code *almost* works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{Info}{rgb}{0.9,0.5,0.0}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{Note}%
{
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[rectangle, rounded corners=15pt, inner sep=15pt, fill=Info](box){%
        \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
          \color{white}
          \mbox{\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont$i$}
          \hfill
          \begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
            \bfseries\BODY
          \end{minipage}
        \end{minipage}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{Note}
  This is a test. This is a test.
  This is a test. This is a test.
  This is a test. This is a test.
  This is a test. This is a test.
  This is a test.
\end{Note}
\end{document}
```

But it renders like this:

[image: Example image]

I'm not sure what TeX is actually aligning that against. What's going on?

If anything, the position of the `i` actually looks OK; it's the body text that seems to somehow be in the wrong place. I can't figure out what's moving it.

So how do I fix this? I'll accept having the `i` fixed to the top or having it vertically centered, just so long as the body text ends up in the right place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have one big `minipage` and inside which you have put the large `i` (without `minipage`) and the body text *inside* another `minipage`. Now due to how much body text you put, the height of the inner `minipage` varies. Since you have not specified the vertical alignment for inner mini page, the default `center` is applied for example,in the following figure, center of mini page is aligned with the center of `x`.

[image]

So you get different looks with different amount of text (height) as always the center is aligned.

As a remedyut the `i` and the body text in separate `minipage`s and you won't need the outer `minipage`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{Info}{rgb}{0.9,0.5,0.0}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{Note}%
{
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[rectangle, rounded corners=15pt, inner sep=15pt, fill=Info](box){%
        \begin{minipage}{0.05\textwidth}
          \color{white}
          \mbox{\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont$i$}
        \end{minipage}
          \hfill
          \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
            \bfseries\BODY
          \end{minipage}
};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{Note}
  This is a test. This is a test.
  This is a test. This is a test.
  This is a test. This is a test.
  This is a test. This is a test.
  This is a test.
\end{Note}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a `tcolorbox` solution. Why `tcolorbox`? You can do lot of beautification with this. For details, refer to its manual.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\definecolor{Info}{rgb}{0.9,0.5,0.0}
\newtcolorbox{Note}[1][i]{
   colback=Info,
   colframe=Info,
   arc=15pt,
   width=\linewidth,
   enhanced jigsaw,
   overlay={
        \begin{scope}[]
            \node[anchor=west,align=center,text width=0.08\linewidth,
                     font=\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont,text=white] at (frame.west) {$#1$};
        \end{scope}},
   left=0.08\linewidth,
   right=10pt,top=10pt,bottom=10pt,
   fontupper=\bfseries,
%   before=\begin{center},
%   after=\end{center}
   }

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{Note}
  This is a test. This is a test.
  This is a test. This is a test.
  This is a test. This is a test.
  This is a test. This is a test.
  This is a test.
\end{Note}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, that fixed the problem - although I still have no idea why...

Comment: So... it's aligning the baseline of the "i" to the middle of the paragraph?